# Enable OpenCL over multiple platforms in Linux? How to proceed with ICD files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opencl, intel, nvidia

### Details

What drivers/packages do I have to install in order to enable OpenCL over multiple platforms: CPU (Intel), Integrated GPU (Intel), Dedicated GPU (NVIDIA)?
It would be nice to have all platforms running OpenCL 1.2 or above

I know it is probably a simple fix, maybe just the right selection of libraries/SKDs, but I am having some trouble getting more them one platform to work.

Running ubuntu 14.04: I have a intel core I5 with the integrated intel graphics and a dedicated NVIDIA Geforce 710m board.

---

### Resources I have used

https://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo
Here (under Debian) it tells me that I only need:

1. Packages of ICD loaders: (you just need one of these)
2. Packages of ICDs
3. Package for headers

---

### What I have already tried

1. Installed CUDA7.5 (yes for all)

   - Had a black screen due drivers conflics

     - Resolved by uninstalling all nvidia drivers and installing 352
     - Still left Cuda SDK install
2. From: [How to make OpenCL work on 14.10 + Nvidia 331.89 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541114/how-to-make-opencl-work-on-14-10-nvidia-331-89-drivers)

   - `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-331-uvm nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-modprobe`
   - Those packages downgraded my drivers to 331 and 340
3. Also from: [How to make OpenCL work on 14.10 + Nvidia 331.89 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541114/how-to-make-opencl-work-on-14-10-nvidia-331-89-drivers)

   - Linked libraries with:

     - `sudo ln -s /usr/include/nvidia-352/GL /usr/local/include`
     - `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libOpenCL.so`
   - OpenCL 1.1 **worked** for NVIDIA GPU
   - Could not get OpenCL 1.2, thus decided to uninstall 331 and 340 and install again 352
4. Installed 352 (again)

   - OpenCL 1.1 **stopped working** for NVIDIA GPU (and still does not work)
5. Installed Intel `opencl_runtime_14.2_x64_4.5.0.8.tgz`

   - Created a simbolic link to intel ICD with:

     - `sudo ln -s /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-4.5.0.8/etc/intel64.icd`
   - OpenCL 1.2 **worked** for CPU (and still works)
6. Installed clinfo `sudo apt-get install clinfo`

   - only intel CPU platform is detected
7. Tried to install several different NVIDIA packages to get NVIDIA GPU work again but had no luck with that

---

### Installed packages and some information:

**ICD in Vendors?**

```
ls -l /etc/OpenCL/vendors/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15 Out 22  2015 Altera.icd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Abr 28 13:48 intel64.icd -> /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-4.5.0.8/etc/intel64.icd
```

Note the missing nvidia.icd

**CL and GL** - GL had a valid link... now is IN RED

```
ls -l /usr/local/include
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Abr 28 12:48 CL -> /usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/CL/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Abr 27 11:44 GL -> /usr/include/nvidia-352/GL (IN RED COLOR - folder doesn't exist anymore)
```

**.so Files**

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/ | grep CL
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    40 Abr 27 11:45 libOpenCL.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1
```

**Installed packages**

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
nvidia-340                  deinstall
nvidia-352                  install
nvidia-libopencl1-340               deinstall
nvidia-libopencl1-340-updates           deinstall
nvidia-libopencl1-352               deinstall
nvidia-libopencl1-352-updates           install
nvidia-modprobe                 install
nvidia-opencl-icd-340               deinstall
nvidia-opencl-icd-352               deinstall
nvidia-prime                    install
nvidia-settings                 install


dpkg --get-selections | grep opencl
nvidia-libopencl1-340               deinstall
nvidia-libopencl1-340-updates           deinstall
nvidia-libopencl1-352               deinstall
nvidia-libopencl1-352-updates           install
nvidia-opencl-icd-340               deinstall
nvidia-opencl-icd-352               deinstall
ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64            deinstall
ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386             deinstall
opencl-headers                  install
unity-scope-openclipart             install
```

**clinfo**

```
clinfo 
Number of platforms:                 1
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 1.2 LINUX
  Platform Name:                 Intel(R) OpenCL
  Platform Vendor:               Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_spir cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_fp64 


  Platform Name:                 Intel(R) OpenCL
Number of devices:               1
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
  Device ID:                     32902
  Max compute units:                 4
  Max work items dimensions:             3
    Max work items[0]:               8192
    Max work items[1]:               8192
    Max work items[2]:               8192
  Max work group size:               8192
  Preferred vector width char:           1
  Preferred vector width short:          1
  Preferred vector width int:            1
  Preferred vector width long:           1
  Preferred vector width float:          1
  Preferred vector width double:         1
  Native vector width char:          16
  Native vector width short:             8
  Native vector width int:           4
  Native vector width long:          2
  Native vector width float:             8
  Native vector width double:            4
  Max clock frequency:               1800Mhz
  Address bits:                  64
  Max memory allocation:             2040185856
  Image support:                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:       480
  Max number of images write arguments:      480
  Max image 2D width:                16384
  Max image 2D height:               16384
  Max image 3D width:                2048
  Max image 3D height:               2048
  Max image 3D depth:                2048
  Max samplers within kernel:            480
  Max size of kernel argument:           3840
  Alignment (bits) of base address:      1024
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                     Yes
    Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:           Yes
    Round to zero:               No
    Round to +ve and infinity:           No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         No
  Cache type:                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:               64
  Cache size:                    262144
  Global memory size:                8160743424
  Constant buffer size:              131072
  Max number of constant args:           480
  Local memory type:                 Global
  Local memory size:                 32768
  Error correction support:          0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:        1
  Profiling timer resolution:            1
  Device endianess:              Little
  Available:                     Yes
  Compiler available:                Yes
  Execution capabilities:                
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:             Yes
  Queue properties:              
    Out-of-Order:                Yes
    Profiling :                  Yes
  Platform ID:                   0x1659390
  Name:                             Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz
  Vendor:                    Intel(R) Corporation
  Device OpenCL C version:           OpenCL C 1.2 
  Driver version:                1.2.0.8
  Profile:                   FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                   OpenCL 1.2 (Build 8)
  Extensions:                    cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_spir cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_fp64
```

---

### So...

How can I get NVIDIA gpu to also show up as a OPENCL 1.2 (or higher) platform? How about the integrated intel graphics?
Would AMD libraries work with my hardware?
Why most of the nvidia packages are marked as `deinstall`?

Comment: ps.: I do have the NVIDIA  board running `sudo prime-select nvidia`

Comment: ps.: I do not have an `*.icd` file in `\usr\share\nvidia-352\ ` . But I had before something linked to nvidia-331 in the `\etc\OpenCL\vendors` folder. Which may have enabled me to use OpenCL 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, three things are necessary:

From https://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo

- Packages of ICD loaders: (you just need one of these)
- Packages of ICDs
- Package for headers

---

Thus for an Intel CPU and a NVIDIA GPU

- Packages of **ICD loaders**:

  - ocl-icd-libopencl1
- Packages of **ICDs**

  - Installed [Intel OpenCL runtime](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers)
  - nvidia-opencl-icd-352
- Package for **headers**

  - opencl-headers

However, to get it to work, it is necessary to make sure the packages are marked as install by `dpkg --get-selections | grep opencl`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-opencl-icd-352 opencl-headers ocl-icd-libopencl1
```

On top of that, you must make sure that intel64.icd and nvidia.icd are in `/etc/OpenCL/vendors` (`ls -l /etc/OpenCL/vendors`).

That said, I had to link intel64.icd with:

```
cd /etc/OpenCL/vendors/
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-X.X.X.X/etc/intel64.icd
```

And, since nvidia.icd was not in the folder (even after the installation of the right package) I had to extract it and manually move from the deb package

```
dpkg -x /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-opencl-icd-352_352.63-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ~/tempfolder
sudo mv ~/tempfolder/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd
rm -r ~/tempfolder
```

---

Finally, make sure nvidia is the active GPU

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
sudo reboot -r now
```

Install and execute clinfo and both platforms should show-up.

```
clinfo 
Number of platforms:                 2
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 7.5.23
  Platform Name:                 NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor:               NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts 
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 1.2 LINUX
  Platform Name:                 Intel(R) OpenCL
  Platform Vendor:               Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_spir cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_fp64
```

Comment: I'm surprised you're able to get Nvidia's OpenCL with using `optirun` when starting `clinfo`. I had to install the packages `bumblebee`, `bumblebee-nvidia` and `primus` in addition to the other packages. Afterwards, running `optirun clinfo` prints both the Nvidia platform and the CPU platform. This was on Ubuntu 15.10. More instructions available at [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).

Comment: I bet you meant "without using `optirun`". With the above configuration, no bumblebee is installed and nvidia runs as default graphics processor after `# prime-select nvidia`. This may be pretty inconvenient if the power consumption is taken in account  (battery lasts half as much), but - I believe - it completely avoids intel on-board graphics card.

Comment: Did you **have** to install those other packages? Before running `clinfo`? What is displayed by `dpkg --get-selections | grep opencl` and `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia`? Are the right packages marked as `install`?
Just to know... What does happen when you run `clinfo` without `optirun`? Does it display the on-board graphics card?

Comment: Yes, I meant "without using `optirun`". I haven't gotten around to installing Intel's GPU runtime yet, the only other OpenCL platform I have is POCL. If I run `clinfo` without `optirun` then I can only access the POCL platform. The packages marked as install are: `nvidia-opencl-icd-352`, `nvidia-352`, `ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64`, `ocl-icd-opencl-dev:amd64`, `opencl-headers`, `nvidia-modprobe`, `nvidia-prime`, `nvidia-settings`.

Comment: Yeah, this seem to be the expected behavior if you use it through bumblebee. The only explanation for me is that before installing bumblebee you did not run `prime-select nvidia` and `reboot`, thus you did not have access to its resources. I will update it on the answer because it is a necessary step. I have not installed Intel's GPU runtime either. It would be nice of you to post the process here if you manage to do it.